# HTML/CSS - Checklist using span and on :focus

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to set the color of a span box to red when I ':focus' on a link. The span changes color on ':active', but nothing seems to happen when I use ':focus'. The categories will output different types of products on click using angular. At the moment, when I click on one of the filters there is no indication that one of the categories has been activated, heavily impacting the UX. I'm hoping to do this with html and css only if possible.

```
<div class="checklist categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a><span></span>All</a></li>
        <li><a><span></span>House Favourites</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

```
.checklist ul li{   
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    list-style:none;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checklist li span{
    float:left;
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
    margin-left:-23px;
    margin-top:4px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d3d7;
  position:relative;    
}

.checklist li a{
    color:#676a74;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
.checklist li a:hover{  
    color:#222;
}

.categories a:hover span{   
    border-color:#a6aab3;
}

.checklist .checked span{
    border-color:#8d939f;
}

.checklist a:active span {
  background-color: red;
}

// This code below is the issue as :focus seems to do nothing

.checklist a:focus span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your selector – `.checklist span:focus span` –   is wrong, it looks like it should be: `.checklist a:focus span`. Further, the likelihood is that `:active` And `:focus` May have comparable specificity.

Comment: I just realised, sorry about that. I changed it as how it was supposed to be, but that still doesn't give me the result I'm looking for, unfortunately.

Comment: Incidentally this was touched on, by Eric Meyer, way back when (in 2007): “[Who ordered the Link States?](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/06/11/who-ordered-the-link-states/)”

Answer (score 0):

I was given a solution for this using Angular and typescript:

[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010493/angular-typescript-change-background-color-of-a-span-when-a-link-is-clicked)