# Angular/Typescript - Change background color of a span when a link is clicked

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, focus

I'm trying to change the color of a span when a link is clicked in order to indicate that it's checked. This must work in the form of a radio button, meaning that the color must disappear if another link is clicked (checked). I tried various methods using only html and css, but unfortunately I never managed to get it to work using :focus. At the moment, when I click on one of the filters there is no indication that one of the categories has been activated, heavily impacting the UX. I believe that this can be achieved using ngClass in angular, however, I'm really struggling to understand how this works. Any help would be really appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="checklist categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-action="filter-link" (click)="changeCategory(null)"><span></span>All</a></li>
        <li><a data-action="filter-link" (click)="changeCategory('House Favourites')"><span></span>House Favourites</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

The styling of the span forms a small checkbox.

Comment: If you are talking about radio-buttons, then don't use spans here. Radio-Buttons have, by HTML, attributes to show which one of a group is selected. So changing the color can be done without and angular/JS, because you can just write a CSS-rule that colors each selected radio-input in a different color. Or am i misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use ngClass [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjuqjb)

in css create your class and write which css you want

```
.active-link span{background-color:green;}
```

in html create ngClass for each list item

```
 <ul>
        <li><a data-action="filter-link" [ngClass]="{'active-link' : menus.allMenu}"  (click)="changeCategory(null,'allMenu')"><span></span>All</a></li>
        <li><a data-action="filter-link" [ngClass]="{'active-link' : menus.houseMenu}" (click)="changeCategory('House Favourites','houseMenu')"><span></span>House Favourites</a></li>
 </ul>
```

then in ts create model for menus

```
menus={allMenu:false,houseMenu:false}
```

with function first initialize it then  change clicked one

```
changeCategory(el,event){
    this.menus.allMenu=false;
    this.menus.houseMenu=false;
    this.menus[event]=!this.menus[event];
  }
```